# G-WAN persist request data in handler

Tags: c, websocket, g-wan

### Solution:

`int session = (int)get_env(argv, SESSION_ID);` to get identifier unique to connection
`US_VHOST_DATA` (vhost) or `US_HANDLER_DATA` (listener) or `US_SERVER_DATA` (server) for data persistent > current connection

Missing pieces:

- either persistent data for connection only
- or some way to execute code when current connection is closed by client (econnreset etc.) or server (e.g. kalive_tmo reached)

This should be solvable as soon as a new HDL_BEFORE_CLOSE state for handlers is added, which makes this question answered for me.

---

### Original Question:

Is it possible in a G-WAN handler to store information persistent to a request/connection (don't really know if "request" applies here)?

To better illustrate what I mean, this is what I got now:

- Client (browser, javascript) sends websocket handshake
- Handler starts, gets into:

  - HDL_AFTER_ACCEPT - here i call gc_init for US_REQUEST_DATA, and get no error
  - HDL_AFTER_READ - here i check for US_REQUEST_DATA which is not yet set, so I do websocket handshake and gc_malloc + set US_REQUEST_DATA, increase KALIVE_TMO, and then return 2 to send data
- Client sees websocket connection as being established, so I (manually triggered some seconds afterwards) send a message
- Handler goes to HDL_AFTER_READ again, **BUT US_REQUEST_DATA is not set**

What I've also tried:
returning 1 instead of 2 in HDL_AFTER_READ -> client gets 404 and handshake does not work

At the moment I'm only using US_REQUEST_DATA to identify if websocket connection is already established and next incoming data should be in websocket message format, so if there is a different (maybe better?) solution, I'm open to that as well of course.

Thanks!

Edit: Added clarification about request/connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why `US_REQUEST_DATA` does not seem to keep your allocated block of memory.

Can you try the [persistence.c](http://gwan.ch/source/persistence.c) example to see if it works as expected for you?

Other than G-WAN persistent pointers, you can use OS services like the Linux shared memory API, etc.

But the G-WAN API should work fine once you copy & paste the example above.

Other values have different scopes:

- US_VHOST_DATA (scope:vhost)
- US_HANDLER_DATA (scope:listener)
- US_SERVER_DATA (scope:server)

Use the session ID below which is unique to each CONNECTION:

```
int session = (int)get_env(argv, SESSION_ID);
```

Comment: Just tried persistence.c and it works as expected. Shared memory doesn't really help me, as my problem is identifying the connection I got. I also just realized that my problem is probably that gwan sees this as different requests on the same connection, but there does not seem to be any persistent connection thing, or is there?

Comment: I think you are right. It treats it as a different request. Is there an identifier that you can use to store in KV and check KV if it already exist. This is interesting I will do some tests using websockets.

Comment: Use **US_VHOST_DATA** (scope:vhost) or **US_HANDLER_DATA** (scope:listener) or **US_SERVER_DATA** (scope:server) with the **int session = (int)get_env(argv, SESSION_ID);** value which is unique to each CONNECTION (your goal).

Comment: Thx! Looks exactly like what I need! There is just one missing puzzle piece: How/when/where would I clear that data again? There doesn't seem to be any kind of HDL_AFTER_CLOSE or the like? So the closest would be using US_HANDLER_DATA, but then memory would fill up with stuff I don't need anymore, and theoretically there seems to be the possibility that 2 sessions could get the same ID (not at the same time hopefully, and only very theoretically, but still...), so I don't wanna handle a different client with the same data

Comment: I suggest you *never* free allocated memory and rather clear it when any given connection is closed. This is faster, simpler and more reliable. Sessions won't have the same IP+ID (you can XOR both 32-bit values).

Comment: And how do I know when a given connection is closed? That's the still missing puzzle piece to me. (I'll very gladly accept this as answer if you could add this missing piece please). Thank you very much as always.

Comment: A new **HDL_BEFORE_CLOSE** state would be handy, I will add it to our to-do list. In the meantime, you can find that this is a new connection when the **SESSION_ID** has changed.